# Exercise using the push-forward measure on a finite sample space?

Tags: probability-theory

For a set of lecture notes, I'm looking for an exercise in modelisation where prior probabilities are assigned on a *finite* sample space using the push-forward measure.

Below is an instance of such an exercise, but the prior probabilities assigned with the push-forward are too "obvious". I am looking for something less obvious, i.e. a harder exercise. More specifically, the uniform sample space should be harder to find.

Example :

*You draw a ball from an urn containing 3 red balls and 2 black balls. Find the prior probabilities on the sample space of colors : $\mathcal{C} = \{R, B\}$ where $R$ stands for "red" and "B" stands for "black".*

*The solution is to artificially number the balls and use the uniform (i.e. equiprobability) measure on the sample space of numbers : $
\mathcal{N} = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$. Then take a map $c : \mathcal{N} \to \mathcal{C}$ that gives the color of the ball for each number. Assume for instance $c(1) = c(2) = c(3) = R$ so that the 3 first balls are red.*

*Define a probability measure on $\mathcal{C}$ using the push-forward measure induced by $c$ : $P(R) = P(c^{-1}(R)) = 3/5$ and $P(B) = 2/5$.*

In this exercise, however, $P(R) = 3/5$ is obvious at first sight, so this seems a little far fetched. Any better example?